# Get count of each item separately in a queryset Django DRF

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

My goal is to get how many `Employee` related to each `Department`. For example, in 1 department works 3 employees, in 2 department works another 2 employees. I figured out how to get all `Employee` count for all `Employee.objects.values('department').annotate(emp_count_in_dep=Count('department')).order_by('department')`.

`models.py`:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dep_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dep_name


class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name
```

`views.py`:

```
class DepartmentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DepartmentSerializer


class EmployeeView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('dep_name', 'organization')
        model = Department

    def get_emp_count_for_dep(self, obj):
        emp_count_for_dep = Employee.objects.values('department').annotate(emp_count_in_dep=Count('department')).order_by('department')
        return emp_count_for_dep


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dep_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # emp_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    # emp_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    emp_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Employee.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        fields = ('emp_id', 'emp_name', 'department', 'dep_count')
        model = Employee

    def get_dep_count(self, obj, emp_id=emp_id):
        # dep_count = Department.objects.values('employee').get(pk=emp_id)
        dep_count = Department.objects.annotate(dep_count=Count('employee')).count()
        return dep_count
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "dep_name": "second department",
        "emp_count_for_dep": [
            {
                "department": 1,
                "emp_count_in_dep": 3
            },
            {
                "department": 2,
                "emp_count_in_dep": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dep_name": "first department",
        "emp_count_for_dep": [
            {
                "department": 1,
                "emp_count_in_dep": 3
            },
            {
                "department": 2,
                "emp_count_in_dep": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This code gives me output from all `Employee` count() for each `Department`:

Desired output:
But I need 3 for first department and 2 for second...

```
[
    {
        "dep_name": "first department",
        "emp_count_for_dep": [
            {
                "department": 1,
                "emp_count_in_dep": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dep_name": "second department",
        "emp_count_for_dep": [
            {
                "department": 2,
                "emp_count_in_dep": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you see, I tried different approaches (using IntegerField and ReadOnlyField), also try `self.instance.pk` = because I need pk as I think this help to solve a problem. I hope, that rewriting `get_dep_count` can help me - such as adding some param, which is `pk`(primary key). I tried previous `dep_count` definition (look at comment line above. I leave it, because it can maybe help you to help me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to include the number of employees per department you can replace this

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('dep_name', 'organization')
        model = Department

    def get_emp_count_for_dep(self, obj):
        emp_count_for_dep = Employee.objects.values('department').annotate(emp_count_in_dep=Count('department')).order_by('department')
        return emp_count_for_dep
```

with something like this

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    emp_count_for_dep = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('dep_name', 'organization', 'emp_count_for_dep')
        model = Department

    def get_emp_count_for_dep(self, obj):
        return Employee.objects.filter(department=obj).count()
```

Comment: Wow! It is so simple. Why I spend 10 hours try to understand how to do it... Either documentation oriented me in a wrong way (I think without pk cannot achieve those). Thank you, @dalvtor  - this answer is really what I need! I'm happy now)

Comment: I am happy to help!